# Send email in python using subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, centos, subprocess

I am trying to send an email with an attachment from CentOS using python. I've below code working fine on windows machine but, when I run this code it gives me an error

> (110, 'Connection timed out')

```
def send_email(self):
    print("Sending an email...")
    try:
        sender = 'xxxxx@domain.com'
        receiver = 'yyyyy@domain.com'
        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = sender
        msg['To'] = receiver
        msg['Subject'] = self.new_folder_name + 'Portal Automation testing results'

        body = 'Hi, \n\n This is my email body. \n\n Thanks.'

        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        filename = self.zip_file_name
        attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        # part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= " + filename)

        msg.attach(part)

        server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.xxxxx.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(sender, "mypassword")
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, text)
        server.quit()
        print('.......')
        print("Email sent.")
        print("-------------------------------------------")
    except Exception as e:
        print('Email can not be sent. Error ====>', e)
```

So, I've used subprocess and it does send an email with attachment but I can't modify the message body as I want. Here is my code,

```
    def send_email(self):

    print('Sending email to xxxxxxx@domain.com')
    body = 'This is email body'

    file_path = '/home/Path/to/file/{}/{}'.format(self.new_folder_name, self.zip_file_name)


    send_email_1 = 'echo {} | mail -s  "Email testing" -a {}  xxxxle@nuance.com'.format(body, file_path)
    send = subprocess.call(send_email_1, shell=True)
```

> Email Output: Hi, /n /nThis is a sample email boby. /n /n Regards

I need help with 1st code sample to make it work on CentOS or 2nd code sample where I can format my email body.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: make sure your body does not have any double quotes. Replace them with single quotes and surround echo argument with double quotes.

Comment: @serbia99 tried 
body = 'This\n \n is email body \n\n Thanks'

send_email_1 = "echo {} | mail -s  {} -a {}  yyyyy@xxx.com".format(body, subject, file_path)  It did not send an email with any attachment and body

Comment: Do not use subprocess.call() with `shell=True`. Really, don't do it. Unless you want failures like you are seeing. That is because it requires you to properly escape the command and assumes the shell is POSIX 1003 compliant. There are various solutions to do the needed quoting but they may or may not be available with version of python you are using and won't work if your `$SHELL` is not POSIX 1003 compliant.

Comment: Your original problem suggests that the system `mail` command is not contacting the same server as your `smtplib.SMTP()` example. So it seems likely you have the wrong FQDN in that statement, a firewall is getting in the way, or something similar is causing the connection timeout.

Comment: @KurtisRader, I had tried removing     shell=True but it gave me an error:    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory and did not send an email. When I use    shell=True, it sends an email at least.

Comment: I am able to send am email using mail command without using subprocess. The problem arises only when I  try to send am email with subprocess.

Comment: Sigh. That's because you're giving `subprocess.call()`  a POSIX shell statement, not a command to run. If instead of a string that is a POSIX shell statement you gave it a list like `['mail', '-s', '"Email testing"', ...]` it will work without `Shell=True`. Using that option is more or less equivalent to `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-c' , send_email1])`. I say more or less because that simple example presumes $SHELL is /bin/bash but you get the idea.